# Calling Proxy lambda from another lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We are designing a serverless service using AWS .

The overall structure is API-gateway -> lambda [L1] -> kinesis -> backend

API gateway -> lambda L1 is proxy mode. i.e. APIG will transfer entire payload to lambda including context like client account id etc

We want to have a retry strategy internally in case processing fails in backend for some reason. For internal retry mechanism, we want to trigger lambda L1 again with same request.

For this we have following solution in mind:

Whenever lambda L1 gets triggered due to API gateway request, we will store entire request in S3. During retry , we will have one separate retry lambda L2, which downloads same request from s3, reads it and triggers lambda L1 with same payload
We have following approaches in mind:
Can we directly use [Invoke API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html#invoke-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest-) directly by passing entire json payload stored in S3.
Will this work considering lambda L1 is connected to API gateway in  proxy mode so has only one trigger?
Is there any challenges in this approach?

Is this recommended way or is there any other better way?

Comment: How big is a request event? Maybe you could store it in sqs, rather then s3. SQS can have dead letter queues which would all you to automatically process and get notified about events that failed to be processed successfuly.

Comment: My usecase is such that, failures can occur in backend processing so those failures won't be caught using a DLQ.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for a Dead Letter Queue like this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#dlq

If you want to ensure everything goes to kinesis you might put something in between like APIGW -> SNS -> (async) Lambda with Dead Letter Queue -> Kinesis.

Here is a good explanation:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/designing-durable-serverless-apps-with-dlqs-for-amazon-sns-amazon-sqs-aws-lambda/

Comment: I want to retry for failures in backend not in lambda. Hence configuring DLQ for lambda won't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like we need to store the incoming requests , so they can be re applied when back errors out.

- We can proxy events from [Api Gateway to DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/) with a set ttl. Let's say your backend can fail in 1 hour, we can set ttl to 1 hour, so, events will be deleted after 1 hour.
- Enable [Dynamo Steams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) and create a Lambda to consume the events.
- When backend fails, update the dynamo record to some status that triggers the update and lambda gets called.

Depending upon record size(if its larger than 400 KB that exceeds Dynamo limit), we can do similar proxy to S3 from Api Gateway and use Lambda based on S3 events.